# Error: Request for member ' ' in ' ' , which is of non-class type ' '

Tags: c++, function, class

I am having trouble identifying the problem with this code...

This is the class declaration:

```
class PersonType{
public:
    PersonType();
    PersonType(string n, int id, string bd);
private:
    string name;
    int ID;
    string birthday;};
```

And this is where the problem comes in:

```
PersonType family[20], newBaby("Anny Dube", 20180912, "2 Sept");

//family initialized here

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    if (family.birthday[5] == newBaby.birthday)
        cout << family.name[5] << " share a birthday with " << newBaby.name;
```

I get his error when running the code:

error: request for member 'birthday' in 'family', which is of non-class type 'PersonType [20]'|

error: request for member 'name' in 'family', which is of non-class type 'PersonType [20]'|

I know the fact that name, ID and birthday are private is an issue, but I know how to fix that. Even if I make the variables public or use accessor methods, I am still left with these two errors...

I have read through a whole bunch of questions relating to this issue but everything I could find is about pointers, misspelled variables, etc.

Nothing seems to help for this...

Please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`family.birthday[5]` should be `family[5].birthday`. You're getting the 5th index of the `family` array (`family[5]`) and then access its `birthday` field.

The same is true for `family.name[5]` => `family[5].name`.

Note however that both `name` and `birthday` are private members, so as it stands now this code will still throw an error. You'll need to either make them public members or create accessors/mutators and call those instead. (thanks @Borgleader!)

Comment: YAY!! That sorted the request for member error I was having, but now i get this error:      undefined reference to `PersonType::PersonType()'   @scohe001

Comment: @BuzzLightYear I see you've declared your default constructor, but did you make sure to *implement* it?

Comment: I FORGOT TO IMPLEMENT THE DEFAULT CONSTRUCTOR!!!! Thank you @scohe001   all problems are now sorted

Comment: You probably actually meant something like `family[i].name`.